# Run Google Ad conversion tag on signup, ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, google-tag-manager, google-ads-api

Google says this should be added to html on the "conversion page".

```
<!-- Event snippet for Website lead conversion page --> <script> gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-sdad/-dsafdsa'}); </script>
```

I have a ReactJS app, so I have no single html "conversion page".

Can I run it from javascript somehow?

```
createAccount = () => {
    Axios.post(`/api/signup`, { user })
      .then(async (resp) => {
        await Axios.post("/api/login", { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password });
        this.props.history.push("/app");
        // Run google ad convert here?
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet). It basically helps you to change something inside `<head>` or `<body>`
So you just need to add that piece of code inside your component responsible for your conversion page.

```
const SignUpPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <!-- Event snippet for Website lead conversion page -->
        <script> gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-sdad/-dsafdsa'}); </script>
      </Helmet>

      SignIn page here
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: @SergeyNikolayevich please elaborate. There might be numerous reasons why it is not working for you. Have you read React helmet documentation? Do you fully understand how it works?

Answer (score 0):

@Arseniy-II, here is the solution which worked for me. Obviously, I found Arseniy's code helpful for me and I added some quotation marks around `gtag`

```
<Helmet>
 <script>{`{"gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-xxx/xxx'});"}`}</script>
</Helmet>
```